# Use homography to warp four corners of image and it returns invalid quadrangle

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, homography

The homography I have is non-degenerate (det!=0), and generated from a valid planar pose. When I use it to warp the four corners of image, it returns something like the following:

```
1 0
3 2
```

instead of something like

```
0 1
3 2
```

where 0 represents top-left corner, 1 top right, 2 bottom left, 3 bottom right. It doesn't follow the clock-wise order anymore, and it's twisted.

The weird thing is, if I apply it to a local patch within the image, i.e. where the plane is, the returned result is valid.

How can this happen? Shouldn't it always return a valid quadrangle?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question in another forum and here is the answer I like: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/73553/55971